# How to search for multiple patterns to delete rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that deletes all rows of an Excel document that contain certain values, let's say "red", "blue" and "yellow".

I found some code that works for a single value. I tried to make some changes but I couldn't get it to work for multiple values.

```
Sub Colors() 

    Dim pattern As String
    pattern = "red"
    RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To RowCount
        Dim j As Integer
        For j = 1 To 1
            If Cells(i, j) = pattern Then
                Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

How do you list more patterns?

Comment: You normally want to delete from the last row up - `For i = RowCount to 1 Step -1`. Then also `Dim i as Long`, not `As Integer`. You also don't need that `For j = 1 to 1` loop. Finally, perhaps consider filtering on the values you don't want, and then deleting visible cells, instead of looping row by row.

Comment: You should avoid looping where possible.  You can Excel's autofilter in this case, it is much faster and easier.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work. You can use a collection to hold all your patterns and iterate through that. Alternatively, you could just use a series of or statements on the If statement instead.

Made a few tweaks to improve this. You may also want to declare a sheet explicitly where you are interacting with cells which I didn't do. Also, I remove the `For j` loop as it wasn't needed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Colors()

    Dim i        As Long
    Dim j        As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim patterns As Collection: Set patterns = New Collection
    Dim pattern  As Variant

    patterns.Add "red"
    patterns.Add "blue"
    patterns.Add "yellow"

    RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = RowCount To 1 Step -1
        For Each pattern In patterns
            If Cells(i, 1) = pattern Then 
                Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                exit for
            end if
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Colors()

Dim pattern As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = RowCount To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1) = "red" Or Cells(i, 1) = "blue" Or Cells(i, 1) = "yellow" Then
       Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

You can use the `or` operator to specify multiple criteria. This searches through column 1, you can change the cell index to adjust your rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Colors()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Color As String

    arr = Array("Red", "Blue", "Yellow")

    'It is better to create a with statement with th workbook you want to work
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'It is better to avoid the usedrange, instead use a specific when you calculating the lastrow
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Loop if you delete you loop from bottom to top
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            'Get the color in cell i column A
            Color = .Cells(i, 1).Value

            'Loop array with colors
            For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                'If color much
                If Color = arr(j) Then
                    'Delete row
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop.  On bigger data sets it takes a really long time.

Don't delete, for the same reason.

Instead: filter, copy your data set to a new sheet, delete the old sheet.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

    Dim mySheetname As String
    Dim mySheetnameOld As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name.
    mySheetname = "Sheet1"
    mySheetnameOld = mySheetname & "_Old"
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets(mySheetname).Name = mySheetname & "_Old"

    ' Add/remove your cell criteria to/from the filter array
    Sheets(mySheetnameOld).Rows("1:" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(mySheetnameOld)
    ActiveSheet.Name = mySheetname

    Sheets(mySheetnameOld).Select
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows("1:" & lastRow).Copy Sheets(mySheetname).Cells(1, 1)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Sheet1_Old").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```